# Not Found (404) error on admin page, CSS gone on blog

Tags: wp-admin, 404-error, site-url, home-url

I manually installed wordpress on my server and the wordpress files are located in "www.mydomain.com/wordpress/", however I wanted my "www.mydomain.com" to be the address for my wordpress blog instead of "www.mydomain.com/wordpress/" so I went to the "Settings->General" screen in my dashboard and changed the "Home" url to "www.mydomain.com/wordpress"
and the "Site" url to "www.mydomain.com" thinking it would make my home address the blog address. When I went back to the admin page I get a "Not Found (404)" error message and all the CSS formatting is gone from my blog.

Is there a way to reset my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got access to the database (via phpMyAdmin or the like) you can change those two values in the `wp_options` table. Look for *siteurl* and *home* in the `option_name` column.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the database setting in wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.org' );  //<------This is what you want users to type into their browser to reach your site.
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.org/wordpress' );  //<-------- This is where Wordpress is installed.
```